# How to get one by one elements in associative array with min value and group PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have associative array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1,
            [product_uname] => AI 92
            [price_per_l] => 44.82
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [product_uname] => AI 95
            [price_per_l] => 46.43
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [product_uname] => AI 95
            [price_per_l] => 46.35
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [product_uname] => AI 92
            [price_per_l] => 44.19
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [product_uname] => AI 100
            [price_per_l] => 53.03
        )

)
```

i need filter array where we group by the ['product_uname'] field and extract after grouping only one unique element with the lowest price [price_per_l] field and sort array by [product_uname] field after that i need to see

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [product_uname] => AI 92
            [price_per_l] => 44.19 (min value price where product_uname = AI 92)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [product_uname] => AI 95
            [price_per_l] => 46.35 (min value price where product_uname = AI 95)
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [product_uname] => AI 100
            [price_per_l] => 53.03 (min value price because there is no any product_name = AI 100)
        )

)
```

can it possible create without loops

Comment: Why without loops?

Comment: What did you already try out, please provide more details.

Comment: i need to get unique elements by product_uname with min price_per_l and don't get elements with the same product_uname field where price_per_l more than minimum values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort on `price_per_l` descending and then index the array on `product_uname` then you will get only the lowest, as later items will replace previous ones and the later items are the lowest price:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'price_per_l'), SORT_DESC, $array);
$array = array_column($array, null, 'product_uname');
```

If needed you can re-index:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
<?php
    $new_array = array();

    foreach($original_array as $key=>$item) {
      if(!isset($new_array[$item['product_uname']])) {
              //There isn't an item for this group in array, save this
            $new_array[$item['product_uname']] = $item;
      } else {
           if($new_array[$item['product_uname']]['price_per_l'] > $item['price_per_l']) {
              //If current item of group has higher price, replace it with this
              $new_array[$item['product_uname']] = $item;  
           }
      }
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1,
            [product_uname] => AI 92
            [price_per_l] => 44.82
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [product_uname] => AI 95
            [price_per_l] => 46.43
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [product_uname] => AI 95
            [price_per_l] => 46.35
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [product_uname] => AI 92
            [price_per_l] => 44.19
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [product_uname] => AI 100
            [price_per_l] => 53.03
        )

);

array_multisort(array_column($array, 'price_per_l'), SORT_ASC, $array);
$array = array_column($array, null, 'product_uname');
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: Where is the educational explanation with this late post?  Why is this answer exactly the same as Abra's answer except for the `SORT_ASC`?